Split a string in and use the resulted array to populate into two separate columns
I have values like this in one of the column PIDS of my SQL Server table. I would like to split this column into two separate columns based on the ID value please. Any value after GID: should go to GID column, and any value after PACKAGEID: should go to PACKAGEID column. Could you please help me with this?



PIDs




GID: 2672, PACKAGEID: 91290


PACKAGEID: 130116, GID: 7d78b


GID: 09e541, PACKAGEID: 17105


GID: 14e3ba, PACKAGEID: 80017


PACKAGEID: 730829, GID: a871c


PACKAGEID: 1009409, GID: c8b2



Expected output - either like this:



GID
PACKAGEID




2672
91290


7d78b
130116


09e541
17105


14e3ba
80017


a871c
730829


c8b2
1009409



or this:



GID
PACKAGEID




GID:2672
PACKAGEID:91290


GID:7d78b
PACKAGEID:130116


GID:09e541
PACKAGEID:17105


GID:14e3ba
PACKAGEID:80017


GID:a871c
PACKAGEID:730829


GID:c8b2
PACKAGEID:1009409




SQL Server has scant native support for regex.  You should consider extracting the GID and PACKAGEID before bringing this data into SQL Server.

What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? A quick search would have quickly shown that T-SQL doesn't support regex, but would have shown you what others have used instead.

Thanks TIM & Dale for response.  this data has imported from CSV files to SQL Server through SSIS package.   CSV file has same combined data so same has been exported to SQL table as well.

Now we have a requirement , to separate these values to individual columns for specific data.  I tried to google different option but could not able to find a best solution in SQL on this. Not sure if we use any .net / python script for this

If you follow @TimBiegeleisen's advice and do the pre-processing in a language that uses the C# regex engine you could extract values for GID and PACKAGEID in each line with the regex ^(?=.*\bGID: *(?<GID>[\da-z]+\b))(?=.*\bPACKAGEID: *(?<PACKAGEID>\d+\b)) that uses named capture groups. Demo. See the answers here for examples on how to extract values of named capture groups.

There are loads of T-SQL solutions available for string splitting with a quick google search if thats the approach you wish to take e.g. string_split

Your data almost looks like maybe it originally came from JSON.  If you instead import that original JSON, you might be able to use SQL Server's JSON functions to extract the values.

what version of sql server ?

You can "onfly" convert PIDs to JSON format and get values separately.

One way of doing this would be some string manipulation to convert the string into an XML element with attributes named GID and PACKAGEID and then use XML methods on that
SELECT PIDs,
       GID = X.value('x[1]/@GID', 'VARCHAR(100)'),
       PACKAGEID = X.value('x[1]/@PACKAGEID', 'VARCHAR(100)')
FROM Data
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (CONVERT(XML,
                '<x ' + REPLACE(REPLACE(PIDs, ': ', '="'),',','" ') + '" />'
            ))) V(X)

Or much the same approach but using JSON instead (which gives a simpler execution plan than the XML one)
SELECT PIDs, GID, PACKAGEID
FROM Data
CROSS APPLY 
     OPENJSON('{"' + REPLACE(REPLACE(PIDs, ': ', '":"'), ', ', '","') + '"}')
WITH 
     (GID VARCHAR(100), PACKAGEID VARCHAR(100))

Fiddle

You can accomplish this by using a combination of CHARINDEX(), LEFT(), and either RIGHT() or STUFF() to manually split the strings in two steps. Serialize the first split strings into a CROSS APPLY(VALUES ...) that feeds the second split. After the second split, the resulting name/value combinations cam be reorganized using conditional aggregation to get your final results.
SELECT *
FROM Data D
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
        MAX(CASE WHEN NV.Name = 'GID' THEN NV.Value END) AS GID,
        MAX(CASE WHEN NV.Name = 'PACKAGEID' THEN NV.Value END) AS PACKAGEID
    FROM (SELECT CHARINDEX(',', D.PIDs) AS Pos) P
    CROSS APPLY (
        VALUES
            (LEFT(D.PIDs, P.Pos - 1)),
            (STUFF(D.PIDs, 1, P.Pos, ''))
    ) I(Item)
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT CHARINDEX(':', I.Item) AS Pos2) P2
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT
            TRIM(LEFT(I.Item, P2.Pos2 - 1)) AS Name,
            TRIM(STUFF(I.Item, 1, P2.Pos2, '')) AS Value
    ) NV
) A

If using SQL Server 2022 or later, you can use the STRING_SPLIT() function to accomplish the same. (Note that the second STRING_SPLIT() below requires use of the enable_ordinal option, not available prior to 2022.)
SELECT *
FROM Data D
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
        MAX(CASE WHEN NV.Name = 'GID' THEN NV.Value END) AS GID,
        MAX(CASE WHEN NV.Name = 'PACKAGEID' THEN NV.Value END) AS PACKAGEID
    FROM STRING_SPLIT(D.PIDs, ',') S
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT
            TRIM(MAX(CASE WHEN S2.ordinal = 1 THEN S2.value END)) AS Name,
            TRIM(MAX(CASE WHEN S2.ordinal = 2 THEN S2.value END)) AS Value
        FROM STRING_SPLIT(S.value, ':', 1) S2
    ) NV
) A

For versions older than 2017, you will need to replace the TRIM() function with LTRIM() or an LTRIM(RTRIM()) combo.
Results:



PIDs
GID
PACKAGEID




GID: 2672, PACKAGEID: 91290
2672
91290


PACKAGEID: 130116, GID: 7d78b
7d78b
130116


GID: 09e541, PACKAGEID: 17105
09e541
17105


GID: 14e3ba, PACKAGEID: 80017
14e3ba
80017


PACKAGEID: 730829, GID: a871c
a871c
730829


PACKAGEID: 1009409, GID: c8b2
c8b2
1009409



See this db<>fiddle for a demo.

This can also be done using text functions availabale in SQL Server.
You can achived the first expected output like this:
with flo as(
SELECT PIDS, SUBSTRING(PIDS,1 ,CHARINDEX(',',PIDS)-1)AS left_side, SUBSTRING(PIDS, CHARINDEX(',',PIDS)+2,255)AS right_side
FROM Data 
), flo1 as (
select case when left(left_side,1)<left(right_side,1) then left_side else right_side end as GID, 
case when left(left_side,1)>left(right_side,1) then left_side else right_side end as Packageid
from flo
)
select substring(gid, charindex(':',gid)+2,255)as gid,
substring(packageid, charindex(':',packageid)+2,255)as packageid
from flo1

And the second expected output like this:
with flo as(
SELECT PIDS, SUBSTRING(PIDS,1 ,CHARINDEX(',',PIDS)-1)AS left_side, SUBSTRING(PIDS, CHARINDEX(',',PIDS)+2,255)AS right_side
FROM Data 
)
select case when left(left_side,1)<left(right_side,1) then left_side else right_side end as GID,
 case when left(left_side,1)>left(right_side,1) then left_side else right_side end as Packageid
from flo

Hope it helps.

You might want to trim your computed data, as there might be some unwanted spaces here and there, see this demo

Sure.Thank you for the observation.

Formatting would make your queries much easier to read.

You can convert PIDs column to JSON and then take JSON_VALUE.
See example
select 
  json_value(jPIDs,'$.GID') GID
 ,json_value(jPIDs,'$.PACKAGEID') PACKAGEID
  ,*
from(
  select *
    ,replace('{"'+replace(replace(pids,':','":"'),',','","')+'"}',' ','') jPIDs
  from test
)a




GID
PACKAGEID
PIDs
jPIDs




2672
91290
GID: 2672, PACKAGEID: 91290
{"GID":"2672","PACKAGEID":"91290"}


7d78b
130116
PACKAGEID: 130116, GID: 7d78b
{"PACKAGEID":"130116","GID":"7d78b"}


09e541
17105
GID: 09e541, PACKAGEID: 17105
{"GID":"09e541","PACKAGEID":"17105"}


14e3ba
80017
GID: 14e3ba, PACKAGEID:     80017
{"GID":"14e3ba","PACKAGEID":"80017"}


a871c
730829
PACKAGEID: 730829, GID: a871c
{"PACKAGEID":"730829","GID":"a871c"}


c8b2
1009409
PACKAGEID: 1009409, GID: c8b2
{"PACKAGEID":"1009409","GID":"c8b2"}



Demo
